# How can I get progress indicator to show up before the data being loaded completely

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image: 1]

This particular code dosent seems to work the way intended

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    city:String?
) {
    Log.d("TAG", "MainScreen: $city")
    val weatherData =
        produceState<DataOrException<Weather, Boolean, Exception>>(
            initialValue = DataOrException()
        ) {
            value = mainViewModel.getWeatherData(city = city.toString())
        }.value

    if (weatherData.loading == true) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
    if (weatherData.data  != null ) {

        MainScaffold(weather = weatherData.data!!, navController)
    }
}
```

This particular code dosent seems to work the way intended

Comment: Shouldn't it be if/else instead of two distinct if statements?

Comment: I tried that earlier but the screen would simply show blank until the data get loaded (no progress indicator)